# How can I see all results from a jquery Ajax response?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax call with jquery, if I put an alert in the success part, it launches the alert, so I know the call is working and there is no errors but if I try to u a value returned from the Ajax call it is null, I would post code but I'm on an iPhone.

How can I basicly see all the results returned? Basicly what php's print_r($bar) does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option (aside from Cody's) is to add a handler for the global `ajaxSuccess` event. When jQuery calls the handler, it passes it the `XMLHTTPRequest` instance, so you can access the `responseText` property directly:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(xhr, settings) {
    alert(xhr.responseText); // Should print the raw response from the server
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use FireBug for Firefox or Stumbler for Internet Explorer.

Comment: I have it but it doesn't show anything useful at all just the sourcode, is there a trick to using it?

Comment: turn on the console for your domain

Comment: view console or net tab. U can see the http requests & responses